# Play YouTube video only after setting display:block

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

When the image is clicked, the video is loaded by changing the display between video and image. But upon page load, the video starts before the click, even while it is `display:none`.

How can I start the video only after the `<div>` becomes `display:block`?

```html
<div onclick="this.nextElementSibling.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
  <img src="http://www.like-agency.it/media/k2/items/cache/d6086de322f98f66cc694f32ea284557_XL.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" />
</div>
<div style="display:none">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/drwLL6I_xPo?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you manage the change of the style from `display: none` to `display: block` then you can include a simple jQuery snippet (inside your event function).

```
$("iframe").attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/drwLL6I_xPo" + "? autoplay=1");
```

Also you have to remove the "autoplay=1" from your actual iframe. Then the video should not autoplay when the div is hidden. Only when you change the src (when div goes `display: block`) the video will autoplay.